# Word to explain this thing people do

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, vocabulary

I find some people do things to show others they are something which they truly not are but only in superficial side. 
For example, a newbie movie freak will start putting all the "top 50" movies of all time posters in his/her room to show others he/she is a big movie enthusiast but you can clearly see he has not done his own research.

Hope you understand.
Please suggest a word to describe this behaviour.

In sports terms someone could be called a *gloryhunter* if he/she starts supporting already championship winning team without being a deep big fan.

Comment: Sounds like "**pretentious**" https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pretentious

Answer (score 3):

A **dilettante** is a person that shows interest or skill in an activity or subject at a purely superficial level.

From the Cambridge dictionary:

> a person who is or seems to be interested in a subject, but whose understanding of it is not very deep or serious

And the OED:

> A person who cultivates an area of interest, such as the arts, without real commitment or knowledge.

If a person brags about their knowledge in a subject, when in fact they are not knowledgeable at all, you might call them a **charlatan** - though this term is often more closely associated with people claiming to be skilled in medicine when they are in fact 'quacks'.

From the OED:

> A person falsely claiming to have a special knowledge or skill.

Answer (score 0):

"wannabe"

e.g. wannabe pop stars practising under the shower

Answer (score -2):

maybe your looking for the word that generally describes that type of people which could be a tag-along, or just simply a follower type of person.

Comment: Maybe. Please can you explain your answer in full? Why could they be this sort of person?